# How to link a variable with another in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Good afternoon, I have a class called Machine, this class has the variable 'state' and 'comment', I want that when the variable 'state' = false then a comment is added, otherwise no comment is added.
I try to create random values, with factory and faker.

```
<?php

/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */

use App\Model;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(Model::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'state' => $faker->randomElement([0,1]),


      //  $factory-> state(machine::class, 'false',[
            'coment'=> $faker->randomElement(['Malogrado','Estropeado']),
        ])//    I tried to do this, but I don't know if this works.



    ];
});
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, can you show the `Machine` class? is it a model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that `Machine` class is a model, you can extract the state out and build the returned array

Set `$state` to random `0` or `1` and use a ternary operator to generate a random element for a `comment` based on whether the `state` is true or false

```php
<?php

/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */

use App\Machine;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(Machine::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    $state = $faker->randomElement([0, 1]);
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'state' => $state,
        'comment' => $state ? $faker->randomElement(['Malogrado', 'Estropeado']) : null,
    ];
});
```

Given a migration that looks like this

```php
Schema::create('machines', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->boolean('state');
    $table->string('comment')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

And seed that data

```php
public function run()
{
    factory('App\Machine', 5)->create(); // Create 5 random machines
}
```

#### Result

```
>>> App\Machine::all();
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3011
     all: [
       App\Machine {#3012
         id: 1,
         name: "Twila Heaney",
         state: 0,
         comment: null,
         created_at: "2019-11-16 16:15:01",
         updated_at: "2019-11-16 16:15:01",
       },
       App\Machine {#3013
         id: 2,
         name: "Dr. Floy Hilpert Sr.",
         state: 1,
         comment: "Malogrado",
         created_at: "2019-11-16 16:15:01",
         updated_at: "2019-11-16 16:15:01",
       },
       App\Machine {#3014
         id: 3,
         name: "Kailey Reilly",
         state: 0,
         comment: null,
         created_at: "2019-11-16 16:15:01",
         updated_at: "2019-11-16 16:15:01",
       },
       App\Machine {#3015
         id: 4,
         name: "Hilbert Lemke",
         state: 0,
         comment: null,
         created_at: "2019-11-16 16:15:01",
         updated_at: "2019-11-16 16:15:01",
       },
       App\Machine {#3016
         id: 5,
         name: "Kathleen Hessel PhD",
         state: 1,
         comment: "Estropeado",
         created_at: "2019-11-16 16:15:01",
         updated_at: "2019-11-16 16:15:01",
       },
     ],
   }
```

Hope this helps